# How to prevent firewall from blocking port 80?

Tags: apache, xampp

I downloaded XAMPP.7zip and extracted it to local disk c: i run XAMPP control panel and i click start button in the apache but it shuts down itself with an error message

> This may be due to a blocked port,missing dependencies
>   improper privilege a crash or shutdown by another method

can anyone help me to run my apache server ?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question - this is systems configuration. Try superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the listening port 80 to something other than 80 say 8888 in **httpd.conf file** of apache.Then  start apache again

Comment: but i find two httpd.conf file

Comment: can you specify the locations

Answer (score -1):

Do you have Skype running ? It usually uses port 80, the same apache uses... So try by quitting Skype, starting apache then restarting Skype ;)

Comment: no i don't have skype